# Do I have to configure Angular 4 when Spring Boot is configured for oAuth2?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, keycloak

I have configured Spring Boot to use oAuth2 to connect with keycloak, then get user information. Everything is working fine when using postman, but when I try to use api from angular something is incorrect.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":null,"ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}

**EDIT1:**

Http configuration:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf().disable().cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*.js", "/*.css","/*.woff2").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().disable()
                .oauth2Login()
                .loginPage(DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI + "/" + realm);
```

Cors configuration:

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Application.properties for keycloak and oauth2:

```
kc.base-url=http://localhost:8180/auth
kc.realm=my-realm
kc.realm-url=${kc.base-url}/realms/${kc.realm}

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-realm.client-id=clientId
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-realm.client-name=clientId
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-realm.client-secret=12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456723
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-realm.provider=keycloak
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-realm.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-realm.scope=email,profile,openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-realm.redirect-uri-template=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/${kc.realm}
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.authorization-uri=${kc.realm-url}/protocol/openid-connect/auth
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.jwk-set-uri=${kc.realm-url}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-info-uri=${kc.realm-url}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.token-uri=${kc.realm-url}/protocol/openid-connect/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute=email
```

Angular request:

```
public getUserDetails() {
return this.httpClient.get<UserDetails>(environment.backendServerAddress + '/user/getUserCache')
    .map(response => response).toPromise();}
```

Spring boot api:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getUserCache", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity getUserCache(Principal principal) {
...
}
```

Do you have any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: adding cookie to Angular request solved my problem
withCredentials:true